# "Use of undefined constant 'LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION'PHP(PHP0415)"

Tags: php, ldap

I am receiving this error when trying to use

> "ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);"

So far, I have made sure that the correct `php.ini` file has `extension=ldap` enabled.

I have also ensured that the file path of the `ext` folder containing my `php_ldap.dll` file for php is correct. I am not sure what else to try, but would love any ideas.

I am working on a local Windows workstation when seeing this error.

Comment: Something is wrong with the way you're loading the ldap extension, because if it's loaded correctly the constant should be defined.

Comment: Did you make sure the extension is properly loaded? I recommend creating an empty php file `phpinfo();` in it to ensure that. Make sure to remove the file afterwards as you should not display this data in production.

Comment: Are you getting this when you run the script? I think this is a Visual Studio warning, not a PHP error.

Comment: @Barmar, yes. It is when I run the script and I am also using VS code. However, the ldap_set_option function is not giving me a warning. It is only the constant.